# Multiple abstracts with acmart

Tags: abstract, acmart

I am trying to put an abstract titled "ABSTRACT" in English with the keywords titled "KEYWORDS" and another abstract titled "RESUMO" in Brazilian Portuguese with the keywords titled "PALAVRAS-CHAVE". Can someone help me? I am using ACM's "sigconf" template (zip files link below).

[LATEX (Version 1.65)](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart-master.zip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the second abstract is not difficult. For the keywords we have to stretch things a bit.

```latex
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[brazil,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\andify\authors}
  {\add@brazil@keywords\andify\authors}
  {}{}
\def\brazilkeywords#1{%
  \gdef\add@brazil@keywords{%
    \@specialsection{Palavras-chave}#1\par
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract in English.

\begin{otherlanguage}{brazil}
\section*{\abstractname}
Este é o resumo em português
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Abc, def}
\brazilkeywords{Ghi, jkl}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @egreg, thank you for your help. I really don't understand much about Latex. Now I have a problem with the order. How do I put the abstract in Portuguese first and then in English? Is it possible to put the keywords after the abstracts and not at the end of both?